# Error when trying to compile method that counts frequency in java

Tags: java

So I'm getting this weird error that I can't seem to figure out, and it's way too long to google so my only help is you guys.

This is the error I'm getting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Rq3.png

Here's the class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.Collections;


public class Ordliste {

private ArrayList<String> liste = new ArrayList<String>();
private int teller, total = 0;


public void lesBok (String filnavn) throws Exception{
Scanner fil = new Scanner(new File(filnavn));
while(fil.hasNextLine()){
  liste.add(fil.next());
} fil.close();
}

public void leggTilOrd(String ord){
for(int t = 0; t < liste.size(); t++)
if(liste.get(t).equalsIgnoreCase(ord)){
  teller++;
} total = total + teller + 1;
System.out.println("Ordet " + ord + " forekommer " + teller + " ganger i                     ordlisten og har naa blitt oekt til " + total + "!");
if (liste.stream().noneMatch(s -> s.equalsIgnoreCase(ord))){
  liste.add(ord);
}
}

 public Ord finnOrd(String tekst){
Ord finneord = new Ord(tekst);
for(int t = 0; t < liste.size(); t++)
if(liste.get(t).equalsIgnoreCase(tekst)){
  return finneord;
} return null;
}

public int antallOrd(){
Set<String> ulikeOrd = new HashSet<String>(liste);
int unique = ulikeOrd.size();
System.out.println(unique);
return unique;
}

public int antallForekomster(String tekst){
int counter = 0;
for(int t = 0; t < liste.size(); t++)
if(liste.get(t).equalsIgnoreCase(tekst))
counter++;
return counter;
}

public Ord[] vanligste5(){
ArrayList<Ord> oftest = new ArrayList<Ord>();
oftest.add(liste.get(0));

int p = -1;
for(int t = 0; t < liste.size(); t++){
  for(int i = 0; i < oftest.size(); i++){
    if(liste.get(t).hentAntall() >= oftest.get(i).hentAntall()){
      p = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  if(p == -1){
    oftest.add(liste.get(t));
  } else {
    oftest.add(p, liste.get(t));
  }
} Ord[] array = new Ord[5];
return oftest.subList(0,5).toArray(array);
}
}
```

Here's the Ord class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;

public class Ord {

private String tekstord;
private int teller = 0;

public Ord(String tekst){
tekstord = tekst.toLowerCase();
teller++;
}

public String toString(){
return tekstord;
}
public int hentAntall() {
return teller;
}

public void oekAntall(){
teller++;
}

public int hentLengde() {
int lengde = tekstord.length();
return lengde;
}

public int plassiDokument(){
int lengde = tekstord.length();
teller = teller * lengde;
return teller;
}
```

}

Comment: That error is pretty clear. "no suitable method found for `add(String)`". You have a collection of `Ord`s, not a collection of `String`s. You can only add `Ord`s.

Comment: Exactly what @resueman mentioned....your arraylist is of type Ord and not String so no method add(String ) exists

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error because `oftest` holds list of Ord objects not list of Strings.

You can do something like this `oftest.add(new Ord(liste.get(0)));`.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of code you have issue:

```
public Ord[] vanligste5(){
    ArrayList<Ord> oftest = new ArrayList<Ord>();
    oftest.add(liste.get(0)); // error place
```

You are trying to add String to collection of Ord. It is not legal operation in java. You should rework this code block according to your specifications.